# Why is jsonData undefined, but only when parsing it to .text

Tags: jquery

I have written a jQuery that submits a form, change some class´s and get a JSON response from my ASP Classic page, this works fine when writing the JSON response to console, and get the correct value back, but when I write it into a .text in the same jQuery I get the error back `Uncaught ReferenceError: jsonData is not defined at HTMLFormElement.<anonymous>`but I cannot figure out why it works one place but not the other.

**My jQuery:**

```
$(function(){
  $("#FullName<%=objFlowDone("ID")%>").submit(function(){
    $.post($(this).attr("action"), $(this).serialize(), function(jsonData){
      console.log(jsonData.Value1);
    }, "json");

    $('#FullNameColumn<%=objFlowDone("ID")%>').fadeIn("slow").removeClass("HiddenDIV");
        setTimeout(function(){
          $('#FullNameColumn<%=objFlowDone("ID")%>').fadeIn("slow").addClass("HiddenDIV");
          
        }, 10000);

    $('#FullNameText<%=objFlowDone("ID")%>').text(jsonData.Value1);
  });

});
```

**The full error from Chrome Developer Tools:**

```
flow.asp?ShowPagePart=FlowDone:1123 Uncaught ReferenceError: jsonData is not defined
    at HTMLFormElement.<anonymous> (flow.asp?ShowPagePart=FlowDone:1123)
    at HTMLFormElement.dispatch (VM44119 jquery.min.js:2)
    at HTMLFormElement.y.handle (VM44119 jquery.min.js:2)
(anonymous) @   flow.asp?ShowPagePart=FlowDone:1123
dispatch    @   jquery.min.js:2
y.handle    @   jquery.min.js:2
```

Comment: jsonData is inside the scope of your post request, and you are trying to pass it outside. Move the $().text(jsonData.Value1) inside your post request, and it should work

Comment: OMG, a matter of scope, yes offcause .., THANK YOU! @Mael, that solved it, it works now :-) .. feel free to send an answer

Comment: @StigKølbæk It's not primarily a matter of scope. It's a matter of timing. In your code, `$('#FullNameText<%=objFlowDone("ID")%>').text(jsonData.Value1);` runs before the `$.post()` request has even returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do any work that depends on the result of an asynchronous function *in the callback* of that function.

```
$(function(){
  var id = '<%=objFlowDone("ID")%>';

  $('#FullName' + id).submit(function () {
    $.post($(this).attr("action"), $(this).serialize(), function (jsonData) {
      // this is the callback, do all the work that depends on `jsonData` in here
      $('#FullNameColumn' + id).fadeIn("slow").removeClass("HiddenDIV");
      setTimeout(function () {
        $('#FullNameColumn' +  id).fadeIn("slow").addClass("HiddenDIV");
      }, 10000);
      $('#FullNameText' + id).text(jsonData.Value1);
    }, "json");
  });
});
```

Comment: That is a much more fine way to do it @Tomalak, than mine, I can see the benefits in it! .. Thank you ! :-)